# "Copy" grayed out in context menu

Tags: firefox, shortcut-menu

The context menu in Firefox sometimes shows **Copy** as greyed out:

[image: Screenshot of the context menu in Firefox with the 'Copy' menu item greyed out]

**Why? And how can I fix it?**

Additional information:

- If it happens, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> still does work
- I can right-click the text several times, but it remains grayed out
- I do not know how to trigger it
- Sometime later, the issue is gone

Answer (score 1):

Click address field then select text you want to copy.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1863246#c14